# jQuery: Nested "data-target" function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".hidden").not(target).removeClass("show");
  target.toggleClass("show");
})
```

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-target=".one">Link One</li>
  <li data-target=".two">Link Two</li>
  <li data-target=".three">Link Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden one">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>

<ul class="hidden two">
  <li data-target=".two_one">Link Two One</li>
  <li data-target=".two_two">Link Two Two</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden two_one">
  Lorem Ipsum Two One
</div>

<div class="hidden two_two">
  Lorem Ipsum Two Two
</div>

<div class="hidden three">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>
```

Generally, it looks how it should look like. **But:** If you click "Link Two" and then "Link Two One" or "Link Two Two", the first navigation should still be visible. The content for "Link Two One" or "Link Two Two" should be added under that. If you click then "Link One" or "Link Three", the content for "Link Two One" and "Link Two Two" should be collapsed (and the "two" navigation of course hidden again).

How is it possible to do that? I would be very thankful for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `.not(this.closest('ul'))` to avoid collapsing `ul`s that are parents of the clicked element:

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".hidden").not(target).not(this.closest('ul')).removeClass("show");
  target.toggleClass("show");
})
```

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-target=".one">Link One</li>
  <li data-target=".two">Link Two</li>
  <li data-target=".three">Link Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden one">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>

<ul class="hidden two">
  <li data-target=".two_one">Link Two One</li>
  <li data-target=".two_two">Link Two Two</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden two_one">
  Lorem Ipsum Two One
</div>

<div class="hidden two_two">
  Lorem Ipsum Two Two
</div>

<div class="hidden three">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>
```